# Bulk upload/update Google Play Games Achievements and Leaderboards

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Does Google Play Games has a batch-uploader for Achievements/Leaderboards like Apple's ITMSTransporter?

I have 64 Achievements, 13 Leaderboards, 12 different localizations with a title, description and image to upload. I don't really want to manually copy-paste over 3000 items.

Answer (score 1):

I had to end up hacking together my own solution to this, using the Chrome javascript console. Very disappointing there doesn't seem to be an official tool or API for this.

You can see the sourcecode for my hacky solution here: https://github.com/zzymyn/gpg-batch-uploader

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I faced the same problem recently (had a huge list of achievements with several localizations that I needed to upload).

There's no ready-made solution but I created my own by leveraging the **Play Games Services Publishing API** (https://developers.google.com/games/services/publishing/). It's a REST API that lets you create and modify achievements and leaderboards. They have clients for several languages, I used the one for Ruby which is what I'm most used to.

It's a bit tricky to set up because the calls need authorization (OAuth 2) and the documentation is not very detailed (I figured out most stuff just by reading their code and samples), but the good part is that once you get it working you get a lot of flexibility.